# svn: E000002: Can't create symbolic link after commit, svn cleanup fails, how can I recover?

Tags: svn, symlink

I added and committed two symbolic links to files that are intentionally not committed, they are to security credentials that aren't supposed to be committed to svn.

```
# svn add submit.cer submit.pkey
A         submit.cer
A         submit.pkey

# svn commit submit.sh submit.cer submit.pkey -m "..."
Sending        submit.sh
Adding         submit.cer
Adding         submit.pkey
Transmitting file data ...
Committed revision 19433.
svn: E200000: Commit succeeded, but other errors follow:
svn: E000002: Error bumping revisions post-commit (details follow):
svn: E000002: Can't create symbolic link '/home/foobar/proj/.svn/tmp/svn-PvrkP3.tmp': No such file or directory

# svn status
svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted

# svn cleanup
svn: E000002: Can't create symbolic link '/home/foobar/proj/.svn/tmp/svn-qckOhQ.tmp': No such file or directory
```

How can I recover from this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best answer, but I have solved my problem for the time being by just popping the hood and getting my hands all dirty. Here is what I did:

I tried to create these missing files but it just asks for others:

```
# svn status
svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted
# touch /home/foobar/proj/.svn/tmp/svn-I03qQS.tmp
# svn status
svn: E155037: Previous operation has not finished; run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted
# svn cleanup
svn: E000002: Can't create symbolic link '/home/foobar/proj/.svn/tmp/svn-lYugyl.tmp': No such file or directory
# touch /home/foobar/proj/.svn/tmp/svn-lYugyl.tmp
# svn cleanup
svn: E000002: Can't create symbolic link '/home/foobar/proj/.svn/tmp/svn-3exWGo.tmp': No such file or directory
# touch /home/foobar/proj/.svn/tmp/svn-3exWGo.tmp
# svn cleanup
svn: E000002: Can't create symbolic link '/home/foobar/proj/.svn/tmp/svn-TSibma.tmp': No such file or directory
```

This is an old version of svn, version 1.7.4 (r1295709) from 2012, but I know better than now trying to upgrade.

Let's see what I can do with wc.db

```
# sqlite3 wc.db .dump |egrep 'submit.(cer|pkey)'
INSERT INTO "NODES" VALUES(1,'submit.cer',0,'',1,'proj/submit.cer',19433,'normal',NULL,NULL,'file',X'2873766E3A7370656369616C2031202A29',NULL,'$sha1$115f82f76a709733e88d9f26a7a5f01a47953401',NULL,19433,1579098137216132,'foobar',NULL,NULL,X'2873766E3A77633A72615F6461763A76657273696F6E2D75726C203337202F69722F73766E2F2173766E2F7665722F31393433332F8888882F7375626D69742E63657229',NULL);
INSERT INTO "NODES" VALUES(1,'submit.pkey',0,'',1,'proj/submit.pkey',19433,'normal',NULL,NULL,'file',X'2873766E3A7370656369616C2031202A29',NULL,'$sha1$99747e06d352668bf515639d0a6ec3dbf86cc1ff',NULL,19433,1579098137216132,'foobar',NULL,NULL,X'2873766E3A77633A72615F6461763A76657273696F6E2D75726C203338202F69722F73766E2F2173766E2F7665722F31393433332F68888882F7375626D69742E706B657929',NULL);
```

So what is that?

```
# sqlite3 wc.db '.schema NODES'
CREATE TABLE NODES (
   wc_id  INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES WCROOT (id),
   local_relpath  TEXT NOT NULL,
   op_depth INTEGER NOT NULL,
   parent_relpath  TEXT,
   repos_id  INTEGER REFERENCES REPOSITORY (id),
   repos_path  TEXT,
   revision  INTEGER,
   presence  TEXT NOT NULL, 
   moved_here  INTEGER,
   moved_to  TEXT,
   kind  TEXT NOT NULL,
   properties  BLOB,
   depth  TEXT,
   checksum  TEXT REFERENCES PRISTINE (checksum),
   symlink_target  TEXT,
   changed_revision  INTEGER,
   changed_date      INTEGER,
   changed_author    TEXT,
   translated_size  INTEGER,
   last_mod_time  INTEGER,
   dav_cache  BLOB,
   file_external  TEXT,
   PRIMARY KEY (wc_id, local_relpath, op_depth)
);
```

Interesting things here: symlink_target

```
sqlite3 wc.db "SELECT symlink_target,NULL,'' FROM NODES WHERE local_relpath = 'submit.cer'"
||
```

so that symlink target is NULL, this could very well be what's throwing it off. Unfortunately I have no case where I can check this:

```
sqlite3 wc.db "SELECT local_relpath,symlink_target FROM NODES WHERE symlink_target IS NOT NULL"
```

nothing.

So, what if I just delete these two NODES?

```
# sqlite3 wc.db "CREATE TABLE BADNODES AS SELECT * FROM NODES WHERE local_relpath IN ('submit.cer', 'submit.pkey')"
# sqlite3 wc.db "SELECT * FROM BADNODES"
1|submit.cer|0||1|proj/submit.cer|19433|normal|||file|(svn:special 1 *)||$sha1$a15f82f76a709733e88d9f26a7a5f01a47953401||19433|1579098137216132|foobar|||(svn:wc:ra_dav:version-url 37 /ir/svn/!svn/ver/19433/proj/submit.cer)|
1|submit.pkey|0||1|proj/submit.pkey|19433|normal|||file|(svn:special 1 *)||$sha1$a9747e06d352668bf515639d0a6ec3dbf86cc1ff||19433|1579098137216132|foobar|||(svn:wc:ra_dav:version-url 38 /ir/svn/!svn/ver/19433/proj/submit.pkey)|
# sqlite3 wc.db "DELETE FROM NODES WHERE local_relpath IN ('submit.cer', 'submit.pkey')"
# cd ..
# svn cleanup
svn: E155010: The node '/home/foobar/submit.cer' was not found.
```

So it still has something about submit.cer now. But from where? Not in the database.

```
# sqlite3 wc.db .dump |fgrep submit.cer |fgrep -v BADNODES
# find . -name 'submit.cer'
# fgrep -Rl submit.cer .
./pristine/2a/2a5fe860af1b54b5b63978176e345b2d6cf57e01.svn-base
./wc.db
```

aha, so this pristine thing. But that is a red herring, this pristine file is just another file submit.sh, which I had committed that contains the submit.cer in its text, so nothing that svn would be aware of. How does `svn cleanup` even know that there should be something named submit.cer?

It mist get this from this column with this value:

```
(svn:wc:ra_dav:version-url 38 /ir/svn/!svn/ver/19433/proj/submit.cer)
```

which is from the column

```
dav_cache  BLOB,
```

with the value:

```
X'2873766E3A77633A72615F6461763A76657273696F6E2D75726C203337202F69722F73766E2F2173766E2F7665722F31393433332F8888882F7375626D69742E63657229'
```

so I better search for all the BLOB columns whether they mention the submit.cer file. And that is not very difficult,

```
# echo "submit.cer" |od -t x1
0000000 73 75 62 6d 69 74 2e 63 65 72 0a
0000013
```

so I can search for:

```
# sqlite3 wc.db .dump |fgrep 7375626D69742E636572
INSERT INTO "WORK_QUEUE" VALUES(209,X'2866696C652D636F6D6D6974207375626D69742E636572203120302031203029');
INSERT INTO "BADNODES" VALUES(1,'submit.cer',0,'',1,'proj/submit.cer',19433,'normal',NULL,NULL,'file',X'2873766E3A7370656369616C2031202A29',NULL,'$sha1$115f82f76a709733e88d9f26a7a5f01a47953401',NULL,19433,1579098137216132,'gschadow',NULL,NULL,X'2873766E3A77633A72615F6461763A76657273696F6E2D75726C203337202F69722F73766E2F2173766E2F7665722F31393433332F8888882F7375626D69742E63657229',NULL);
```

so there I go, that WORK_QUEUE!

```
# sqlite3 wc.db '.schema WORK_QUEUE'
CREATE TABLE WORK_QUEUE (
   id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
   work  BLOB NOT NULL
);

# sqlite3 wc.db 'select * from WORK_QUEUE'
209|(file-commit submit.cer 1 0 1 0)
210|(file-commit submit.pkey 1 0 1 0)
```

nice! So if I just move these out of the WORK_QUEUE?

```
# sqlite3 wc.db 'CREATE TABLE BAD_WORK_QUEUE AS SELECT * FROM WORK_QUEUE'
# sqlite3 wc.db 'DELETE FROM WORK_QUEUE'
```

and now tada!

```
# cd ..
# svn cleanup
# svn status |fgrep submit
?       submit.cer
?       submit.pkey
```

this looks really promising, as if the bad links were never committed? Shall we try? Ooops:

```
# svn update
Updating '.':
   C submit.pkey
   C submit.cer
Updated to revision 19433.
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 2
```

but then, magically:

```
# svn update
Updating '.':
At revision 19433.

# svn status |fgrep submit
D     C submit.cer
D     C submit.pkey
```

That's very neat! So I can survive my work further, just won't commit these symlinks ever again.

For now the lesson is: never commit a symlink without also committing the target!?